# How can I access a property in data

Tags: vue.js

As you can see below, `isChecked` is a reactive property that if when I click the checkbox, it will change to `true` if checked and `false` if not.

[image]

Now, when I try to access it,

```
methods:{
    getChecked(){
        console.log(this.$route)
       //when I do console.log(this.$route.isActive), result is undefined.
    },
},
```

`isActive` property is not displayed in the console. 
[image]

As you can see, `isActive` is not there. I would like to access `isActive` so that I can get its status as true or false.
 Is there anyway I can access `isActive` property? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but your question is not clear. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @Phil Please see my update :)

Comment: But `this.$route` is the [route object](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object), not a component

Comment: @Phil Ah okay, and how can I access `isActive`?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean. In your component, you would just use `this.isActive`. I think you may be misinterpreting your console output. `isActive` and `isChecked` are not part of the `$route`

Comment: @Phil Mmmmm, but it's undefined :S

Comment: Pay attention to your first screenshot: your surrounded properties are _siblings_ of `$route`, not children of it.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking. What component is your `getChecked()` method a part of? What component is the `isActive` property part of?